# Horizontal scroll bar occludes text

Tags: bug, google-chrome, code-block, mac

I've been running into this lately.  The scroll-bar gets stuck and makes it difficult to read the text.  I'm running Chrome `Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)` on macos.

[image]